# logged in users only for /user in user menu

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

In my user menu I have a link for /user which produces a my account link which works as expected.  In the menu admin (logged in users only) appears next to it.

Now, when I translate the item to produce a link to /user I have found that 'logged in users only' does not appear next to it and that it is shown whether the user is logged in or not.

Is this a known bug?  Anyone know how i might solve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suppose since /user is open to both authenticated and non authenticated users the other /user is somehow specially defined.

For others looking for a quick fix, I solved this with menu item visibility module.